# Sharepoint Online IRM to particular file/folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, irm, information-policy

I have a requirement to apply Microsoft Information Rights Management (IRM) to a particular file or a folder inside a document library. Different folders should have different policies applied as users accessing these folders are different.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: You can share more details on what IRM policies do you want to apply.

Answer (score 0):

**In short,** you can't apply the IRM for a specific file, folder or list item level!

> IRM is only applied to the **entire** lists or libraries.